# Reading binary data in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to transport a blob of binary data from a file (PNG image) over XML-RPC in elisp. This is part of automatically uploading attachments to the Confluence wiki, specifically local images used in the current page.
The code doing this is:

```
        ;; Open the file and get content
        (with-temp-buffer
          ;; file-name is the PNG file name, which is binary data
          (find-file (expand-file-name file-name current-dir))
          ;; Setup Confluence request alist
          (setq confl-req (list 
                           (cons "fileName" file-name)
                           (cons "contentType" mime-type)))
          ;; RPC call
          (setq confl-reply (cfln-rpc-execute 'confluence1.addAttachment
                                              page-id confl-req (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))
```

I am having a problem with the piece `(buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))`. The binary data uploaded to Confluence does not match the PNG file at couple of locations. I noticed that the bytes `0xe0 0x88` were replaced with `0xc8` in the attached file. Any idea how to get the exact binary data contained in a file?

Thanks,
NMA

Answer (score 3):

You should use `insert-file-contents-literally` instead of `find-file`.

```
(insert-file-contents-literally FILENAME &optional VISIT BEG END
REPLACE)

Like `insert-file-contents', but only reads in the file literally.
A buffer may be modified in several ways after reading into the buffer,
to Emacs features such as format decoding, character code
conversion, `find-file-hook', automatic uncompression, etc.

This function ensures that none of these modifications will take place.
```

Comment: This worked great! Can I use (buffer-string) after this? I don't want the text properties to be returned.

Comment: @NarendraAcharya there probably are no text properties, but it's safer to use `buffer-substring-no-properties`

Answer (score 0):

a one stop solution that goes in the line of @npostavs answer is provided by the f-library:
https://github.com/rejeep/f.el

```
f-read-bytes
```

it uses

```
insert-file-contents-literally
```

together with

```
buffer-substring-no-properties
```

takes care of encoding and multibyte handling ....